# How to get a user log failed details in log file

Tags: php

In a log file I want get a how many times user is log failed and the date details I have code for this but its not working correctly.

This is a code

```
$file = new SplFileObject("failed.log", "r");

while(!$file->eof()) 
    {   
      $data[] =  current (($file->fgetcsv("|"))) . next (($file->fgetcsv("|")));            
    }

$abc = implode(",", $data);
echo $abc;  

$br = "\n";
```

In this code I am getting like this

```
John26:Dec:2017:16:15:27,Abc29:Dec:2017:09:39:45,Bhumi29/Dec/2017 14:15:41,Abc
```

Its not correct, it read first line name and and second line date I don't no what is wrong in my code.

This is my log failed details

```
John|26:Dec:2017:16:09:45|192.168.0.101|CentaurOne|Failed
cena|26:Dec:2017:16:15:27|192.168.0.101|CentaurOne|Failed
Abc|27:Dec:2017:09:25:25|192.168.0.101|CentaurOne|Failed
Bhumi|29:Dec:2017:09:39:45|192.168.0.101|CentaurOne|Failed
Bhumi|29:Dec:2017:10:19:28|192.168.0.101|CentaurOne|Failed
Avccc|29/Dec/2017 14:15:41|192.168.0.101|CentaurOne|Failed
Abc|04/Jan/2018 15:54:35|192.168.0.101|CentaurOne|Failed
```

Comment: Why are you not putting failed attempts in the database? You then just need to do a query. Your also storing user passwords in plaintext on the filesystem  I see no code for counting.

Comment: This for example I have log file in that file I want get a how many times user logged in and also i want a date details I done a code for counting i don't know how get a date details please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you should rethink saving failed logins to a text log especially if you intend to make this a routine action. As the file grows, it will become memory intensive:

```
# Saves contents of file into array by end of lines
$explode = file("failed.log",FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
# Loop rows
foreach($explode as $row) {
    # Explode the | character
    $exp    =   explode('|',$row);
    # Save the user to the an array
    $new[$exp[0]]['dates'][]    =   $exp[1];
    # Count how many times tried
    if(!isset($new[$exp[0]]['count']))
        $new[$exp[0]]['count']  =   1;
    else
        $new[$exp[0]]['count']  +=  1;
}

print_r($new);
```

Should give you:

```
Array
(
    [John] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26:Dec:2017:16:09:45
                )

            [count] => 1
        )

    [cena] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 26:Dec:2017:16:15:27
                )

            [count] => 1
        )

    [Abc] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 27:Dec:2017:09:25:25
                    [1] => 04/Jan/2018 15:54:35
                )

            [count] => 2
        )

    [Bhumi] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 29:Dec:2017:09:39:45
                    [1] => 29:Dec:2017:10:19:28
                )

            [count] => 2
        )

    [Avccc] => Array
        (
            [dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 29/Dec/2017 14:15:41
                )

            [count] => 1
        )
)
```

Use `print_r()` to see how to access array key/values.

Comment: How can I convert in to a text line. like this //John CentaurOne 26:Dec:2017:16:09:45 count => 1
  //cena CentaurOne 26:Dec:2017:16:15:27 count => 1                
  //Bhumi CentaurOne 29:Dec:2017:09:39:45 29:Dec:2017:10:19:28 count => 2

Comment: If you save the right contents into the main array, you can just loop over the array and create the string (or an array to implode with `PHP_EOL` at the end).

Comment: Tnx .  It's working for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
{ 
    $tmp = implode(";".PHP_EOL, $abc[$i]); // splits the string, returns an array
    $firstword = $exp[0] .$exp[3] . $exp[1] . "=".$new[$exp[0]]['count']."<br>";
}